# Play Framework How to Compile Views for Distribution

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.2

I have common views that I want to share across multiple Play Framework 2.2.1 applications.  I'm thinking packaging them up into a single library and publishing them to our Maven repo is the way to go, but something isn't working correctly during the compile phase.

My project has a single file My/Namespace/myView.scala.html.  After compiling my package jar has a file named exactly as my view.  My/Namespace/MyView.scala.html I was expecting to see some class files.

The play framework seems to do something very similar https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/twitterBootstrap/twitterBootstrapFieldConstructor.scala.html and looking at their Maven package this seems to compile into a twitterBootstrapFieldConstructor class (along with all the meta classes scala generates):

[image: compiliation of play view]

I'm guessing i'm missing something in my SBT configuration that makes it compile scala.html files...but i'm just not seeing it.

Anyone have some insight into what i should be doing?

Comment: Do you extend you sbt project from play project for this build?

Comment: @1esha i do not, but i'm open to that option

Comment: Those classes are generated as part of building generated-sources. I think first thing you should try is to extend your project from Play project in sbt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the best option at this time is to make use of the Twirl library https://github.com/spray/twirl which is the template engine wrapped up into a similar but distinct API.

sbt .13 support is in a testing phase see https://github.com/spray/twirl/issues/15#issuecomment-32272389 as it appears there's going to be some reconciliation of this project & play's templating libraries (one using the other)